# Running update from SQL Developer with different results as from package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to run an update within an cursor ('cur_palettenkosten') operation in an plsql procedure.

I narrowed down, that the enclosing cursor has data and that the update does not affect any rows (output sql%rowcount)

```
PROCEDURE p_ref_lschein_rueckstellungen AS

 for cur_palettenkosten in (
    select land, spediteur_nr, plz_von, plz_bis,  preis, gueltig_von, geultig_bis, gzp.behaelter_nr
    from spediteur_fahrtkosten sp,gutschrift_zuord_pal gzp 
    where sp.behaelter_nr = 1 
    )

    LOOP

        UPDATE lschein_rueckstellungen
           SET preis = cur_palettenkosten.preis
          WHERE to_number(sped_nr) = to_number(cur_palettenkosten.spediteur_nr) 
           AND to_number(lhm_typ) = to_number(cur_palettenkosten.behaelter_nr)
           AND to_char(kst) = to_char(cur_palettenkosten.land);

        dbms_output.put_line (cur_palettenkosten.spediteur_nr || ' '||cur_palettenkosten.behaelter_nr|| ' '|| cur_palettenkosten.land || sql%rowcount);

    END LOOP;
COMMIT;

END p_ref_lschein_rueckstellungen;
```

Running the script from the editor this way:

```
BEGIN
    p_ref_lschein_rueckstellungen;
END
```

does have any effect on the table 'lschein_rueckstellungen' which I wanted to update.

Running it from the same editor window like this:

```
BEGIN
    <procedure content copied here>
END
```

updates the data as desired.

Are the any ideas, what I did wrong?

Comment: Sure, but how to find out!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got that ... I did it all from one SQL Developer Instance. Running the procedure from a compiled package does nothing to the data. Copying the content of the procedure to an editor window and run it, changes the data.

Comment: I added the info you requested to original question.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you open a new session per tab? Then of course you have to commit the update!

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but we executed the script and the anonymous block from the same editor tab.